# PHP + SQL - Using SQL Server 'Create To' scripts to create tables through PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, create-table, web-development-server

In SQL Server you seem to be able to get the CREATE TABLE script by right clicking a table, 'Script Table As...' and selecting 'Create To'. I've copied the output script and while it does seem to work and create the table when pasted onto the 'New Query' window, it does not work when used in PHP.
Example code:

```
$sqlcommand = 
"CREATE TABLE [dbo].[departments](
    [department_pk_fk] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [des] [varchar](100) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_departamentos] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [department_pk_fk] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
";
$site_api->execQuery($sqlcommand);
```

Anyone have any useful input about why this would happen?

Edit: `execQuery` code:

```
public function execQuery($q,$scalar=FALSE,$returns=FALSE) {  
//return an assoc array or a scalar
    global $Cfg, $site_api;

    $this->query=$q;


    try {
      $result_array = array();
        $result = $this->conn->query($this->query);
        if (is_bool($result)===TRUE) {  //if reslt is true or false then there is nothing to do
            return $result;
        } else {
            if (!$scalar) {
                if ($result->rowCount()==0)
                    return null;
                //SQLSRV
                while($row = $result->fetchAll(SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    $result_array[]=$row;
                }
                $result->closeCursor();
                if($returns) return $result_array[0];
            } else {
                $row = $result->fetchAll(SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC);
                if($returns) return $row[0];
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        print "Error Code <br>".$e->getCode();
        print "Error Message <br>".$e->getMessage();
        print "Strack Trace <br>".nl2br($e->getTraceAsString());
    }
}`
```

Comment: Why do you think that something "does not work"? Is there any error message involved?

Comment: It simply does not create a table, no errors thrown, and if I try, `$something = $site_api->execQuery($sqlcommand);` it returns false. Meanwhile all other scripts work with the same function.

Comment: How do you check for errors? Is it usual that `execQuery` returns false?

Comment: `execQuery` and `site_api` as a whole were made by someone else and I use it as it's usually more convenient. I understand it should return error messages. Usually, when it doesn't work, I just try to run the code on said SQL Server and see if it works, what errors there are, and feed the correct script onto the function. `execQuery` returns the result of the query, so the query should be giving out false. I'll include the `execQuery` script in the question.

Comment: Are you sure that an exception is thrown in case the query is not executed? Probably, `execQuery` should check for errors additionally

Comment: As I said, I understand that `execQuery` should throw exceptions. I haven't seen it happen yet. Usually it just fails silently, which makes me go and check the script in SQL Server itself. After I correct it, works like a charm. The issue here is that while `execQuery` is tried and true that it works with correct scripts (My whole project runs on it), it's not happening right now. This particular script works in SQL Server but not when input by PHP into `execQuery`, and that's the first time it happens.

Comment: Yeah, then please add additional error checking. According to the documentation, [query](http://php.net/sqlsrv_query) does not throw any exceptions that could be caught.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I am fairly knowledgeable at PHP but not at that point. I'm only just a 12th grade programming student.
Edit: Also, the last part about `Catch(Exception $e)` is a leftover from when the code was made to work with MySQL. As project requirement moved to SQL Server, I changed the functions into their SQLSrv counterparts but that was left over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `CREATE` statement is correct, just remove the keyword `GO` from your script. The `GO` keyword is not part of T-SQL, it is SQL Server utilitiy [statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-2017).

Because I don't know how your class is written, I've made a simple script for test using PHP Driver for SQL Server (`SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC` constant is specific for this driver). It works correct without `GO` statement and gives error with this statement (PHP 7.1 and SQL Server Express 2012).

```
<?php
$server = 'server\instance,port';
$cinfo = array(
    "Database"=>'database'
);

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $cinfo);
if( $conn === false )
{
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

$sql = 
    "CREATE TABLE [dbo].[departments](
        [department_pk_fk] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
        [des] [varchar](100) NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [PK_departamentos] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
        ([department_pk_fk] ASC) WITH (
            PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
            STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
            IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
            ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
            ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
        ) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if( $stmt === false ) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn);

echo 'OK'."</br>";
?>
```

If you don't know how the SQL statement is verified, try to remove schema name (`dbo`), brackets for object names (`[]`), because there can be some additional syntax corrections in class method.

Other things, that can cause problems are permissions.

You can always use `sqlsrv_errors()` to get additional information about specific errors.

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. However, removing `GO`, `[dbo].` any and all `[]` worked like a charm. If you feel like editing your answer to include this fact, I will accept it.

Comment: @LuísMiguel I've updated the answer. I'm glad to help, but I think that there is some additional syntax correction in class methods.